# woocommerce custom field configuration

Tags: php, wordpress

I need your help. Its my first time when I use woocomerce in WP and I don't know how to add custom button. On public product view I must add button with link to  selected wikipedia page. On private admin product view I need custom url or text field in (wp-admin->product->add product).

Okey now I create custom field and taxonomiex but I don't know what next. 
I tried to find some tutorials but I did not give advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had a similar situation like this. I purchased a plugin to fix it due to tight deadline. You can do it using below methods:

1) By using ready to use plugins

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-custom-product-data-fields/screenshots/
  (Free one)
- https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-custom-fields-product-addons/11332742
  (Paid one)

2) You can also create a plugin by yourself

Basically a plugin will allow you to modify the site as you require without modifying the wordpress core. Learn about **Hooks and Filters.**

I would suggest you to go with 2nd option, learn to develop plugins so that it will be helpful for you in the long run. Read the documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API. It will take some time but it is worth it.

Comment: I'm using Advanced Custom Fields but I don't know how customieze it.

Comment: Can you post the code which you have tried till now.

Comment: If you are not clear how to use the "Advanced custom fields" check the youtube sample videos. I am sure you can learn it form there.

Comment: You will have to devote some time to get to know the inner details of it. Once you are clear with that you can definitely modify it any how.

Check some of the videos : https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Advanced+Custom+Fields&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Ts2MV97OI47j8weoyquIDA#q=Advanced+Custom+Fields&safe=off&channel=fs&tbm=vid